# FCM Android - On click Notification - Open webview

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-webview

Template which I was using : https://github.com/mgks/Android-SmartWebView
Actually, the template has no fcm feature.  I added it manually.  I referred here so as you look into mainactivity file.

I want to open specific link when user clicks my notification.

My notification Builder is:

```
// pending implicit intent to view url
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("LINK",link);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, ADMIN_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getBaseContext().getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))  //set it in the notification
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)  //a resource for your custom small icon
                .setContentTitle(title) //the "title" value you sent in your notification
                .setContentText(message) //ditto
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)  //dismisses the notification on click
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .setSummaryText(message)
                        .bigPicture(bitmap)
                        .setBigContentTitle(title));
```

I tried this in MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null && getIntent().getExtras().getString("link", null) != null && !getIntent().getExtras().getString("link", null).equals("")) {
            String url = null;
            if (getIntent().getExtras().getString("link").contains("http")) {
                url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
            } else {
                url = "http://" + getIntent().getExtras().getString("link");
            }
            aswm_view(url, false);          
        } else {
            //Rendering the default URL
            aswm_view(ASWV_URL, false);
        }
        (near lines 250)
```

But, Nothing is working.  Can anyone please help me?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> intent.putExtra("LINK",link);
>
> String url = getIntent().getString("link", null)

This is my mistake.  (LINK & link are different.

I spend near 1 weeks for this silly mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `intent.getString()` instead of `intent.getExtras().getString()`:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String url = getIntent().getString("link", null)
if (url != null) {
    if (!url.startsWith("http")) {
        url = "http://" + url;
    }
    aswm_view(url, false);          
} else {
    //Rendering the default URL
    aswm_view(ASWV_URL, false);
}
```

According to [Intent.getExtras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getExtras()) your `intent.getExtras()` would return `null` because it was never assigned.

> Returns the map of all extras previously added with putExtra(), or null if
>   none have been added

Comment: I will try it soon.